# can I connect to remote WebLogic server on solaris from eclipse on windows

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, solaris

I need to connect to remote weblogic server on solaris system from eclipse on windows,
when i give him weblogic home in eclipse he say the path "/home/wlsadm/" does not contain a valid weblogic server install.
Can i connect in this state, if true then what is the right path for weblogic home on solaris ans also the right path for java home.

Comment: How about making sure the path to the server is shared and mounted to your computer as, for example, F:? Then just add it as you would if it actually was located on your hard drive. Another thing to ask is, why do you want to do this? If it is for debugging purposes, you could probably toggle some remote debugging.

Comment: This is good idea but I don't know if success or not.
I need this for run and debug purpose but at all how can I use remote debugging from eclipse on my machine?